# How to change Microsoft Expression Web doctype to HTML 5

Tags: html, microsoft-expression-web

I am using Microsoft Expression Web, and I have this problem: When I create a new *HTML* file, I get this:

[image]

How can I change from `XHTML 1.0` to `HTML 5`?

Comment: Where is your `<head>` tag? `<meta>` should be inside of `<head>`, not `<html>` This is what the message in popup tells your about.

Comment: Tutorial with screenshot: https://www.thesitewizard.com/expression-web/how-to-make-expression-web-use-html5.shtml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to change the doctype from XHTML 1.0 to HTML5 in the newly created file, replace the first line with `<!doctype HTML>`. If what you're asking is how to make this the default, then according to [Microsoft's documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc295208.aspx):

> **To set the default DocType declaration that Expression Web inserts when you create new pages**
>
> On the **Tools** menu, click **Page Editor Options**.
>
> In the **Page Editor Options** dialog box, on the **Authoring** tab,
> select the **Doctype** and **Secondary Schema** you want to use for all new
> files.